# Знаки препинания в несобственно-прямой речи; строение фразы

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, несобственно-прямая-речь

> Помните: в воскресенье (так считается) каждый уважающий себя гражданин
>   присутствует на мессе, в любом случае – всегда посвящает этот день
>   семье, потому практически ничего и нигде не работает. Особенно в
>   крохотных городках. Понедельник тоже день опасный – потому что те, кто
>   всё-таки открылся ради туриста в выходной, закроются теперь в
>   понедельник. **А некоторые думают: всё равно никто не разбирает
>   понедельник/воскресенье не рабочий, хорошего не жди и просто не
>   работают два дня…** Алгоритм не угадать.

А если так:

*А некоторые хозяева заведений думают: всё равно никто не разбирает, что там нерабочее - понедельник или воскресенье, но хорошего не жди - и просто не работают два дня…*

Никак не выпутаюсь...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помните: в воскресенье (так считается) каждый уважающий себя гражданин присутствует на мессе, в любом случае – всегда посвящает этот день семье, потому практически ничего и нигде не работает. Особенно в крохотных городках. Понедельник тоже день опасный – потому что те, кто всё-таки открылся ради туриста в выходной, закроются теперь в понедельник. **А если публика не знает, какой день нерабочий, то ждать хорошего не приходится и проще не работать оба дня… Алгоритм тут не угадаешь.**

Answer (score 2):

**А некоторые хозяева заведений думают: всё равно никто не разбирает, понедельник или воскресенье нерабочий день, хорошего не жди — и просто не открываются два дня… Алгоритм не угадать.**

Устранено повторение: не рабочий....не работают.

Answer (score 1):

> потому что те, кто всё-таки открылся ради...

потому что магазинчики, открывшиеся ради...

> но хорошего не жди

но прибыли не жди